# In tensorflow, does tf.summary record average values over multiple steps?

Tags: tensorflow

By default, `RunConfig.save_summary_steps` is 100 in `tf.estimator.Estimator`, so it saves summaries every 100 steps. At each time it saves a summary, does it just save the current summary value computed from the current `step/minibatch`? Or it saves the average summary values computed from the recent 100 `steps/minibatches`? I cannot find a clear description for this in the official documentation.

Comment: I believe the answer is "current". The current values over thousands of iterations would show you the trend.

Comment: What particular estimator are you using?